# Redirecting output to both stdout and a file

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, io-redirection

I want to redirect the output of a command in a terminal to both stdout and a file. Also I want to run the command with `nohup` so I can log out from the machine.

I did this way:

```
nohup python ./script.py 2>&1 | tee out.file
```

The problem is that the output of the script should rewrite the same line (it's a loading stuff). If I run it with the above command, it doesn't rewrite the same line, instead it prints every step of the loading on a new one like this:

```
25%[=============>______________________________________]
.
.
50%[===========================>________________________]
```

As there is really lots of loading in this script and I don't want to have so huge output file with just loading lines, is there any way to avoid this? I can't change the code of the script.

Omitting the output to stdout would be ok (essential is the output to the file), but the file still contains each loading step on a different line.

Comment: Pipe the output through a `grep` or `sed` command to filter out those progress lines, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it could be what I should do. I just need the last progress line, but it could be achieve with grep or sed, thanks.

Comment: if done right progress status should be in stderr, just redirect the stdout instead.